# JavaFX 8 3D : провести Cylinder от точки А до точки B, заданных Point3D объектами

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

Возникла необходимость **соединить две точки цилиндром**.
Есть координаты двух точек, заданных, как экземпляры `Point3D`:

```
Point3D pointA = new Point3D(100,200,150);
Point3D pointB = new Point3D(200,150,-100);
```

Есть группа (`javafx.scene.Group`), в которой производятся построения:

```
Group space3D = new Group();
```

**Задача:** соединить эти две виртуальные точки (можно разместить в этих координатах по экземпляру `Sphere` радиусом `10`, для наглядности) экземпляром `javafx.scene.shape.Cylinder` радиусом 2, высотой равной расстоянию от точки А до точки B с минимальным количеством действий.

**П.С.:** Какие альтернативы были бы более эффективными для визуального соединения двух точек в 3D пространстве?

Comment: Смотрите что я нашел в исходниках GeoGebra: [вот](https://github.com/geogebra/geogebra/blob/41f3d9c48765abbb4997d4c5730f7c03ec84ac8c/common/src/main/java/org/geogebra/common/geogebra3D/kernel3D/algos/AlgoQuadricLimitedPointPointRadiusCylinder.java). Правда тут разбираться и разбираться :)

Comment: @Sergey Pestov, спасибо за интересную ссылку. Если кратко, там именно строится цилиндр по двум точкам и радиусу:  берут точки,  создают  два основания с заданным радиусом и соединяют. Понятное и правильное решение в плане геометрии. Как бы Вы эффективно реализовали это решение в JavaFX? (Замечу, что цилиндр уже представлен в JavaFX как  графический примитив.)

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте использовал что-нибудь другое для 3D.

Comment: Есть что либо проще и переносимее, чем javaFX? Пожалуйста, расскажите!

Comment: Например, [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/). Будет работать в любом браузере и возможностей больше. [Пример](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Geometries/CylinderGeometry).

Comment: Спасибо, интересный инструмент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начну от обратного.Пример решения:

```
public Cylinder paintCylinder(Point3D A, Point3D B) {

    Point3D temp = A.subtract(B);
    double Y = temp.getX() != 0 || temp.getZ() != 0 ? B.getY() : B.getY() > A.getY() ? B.getY() : A.getY();


    Point3D dir = A.subtract(B).crossProduct(new Point3D(0, -1, 0));

    double angle = Math.acos(A.subtract(B).normalize().dotProduct(new Point3D(0, -1, 0)));

    double h1 = A.distance(B);

    Cylinder c = new Cylinder(2d, h1);

    c.getTransforms().addAll(new Translate(B.getX(), Y - h1 / 2d, B.getZ()),
            new Rotate(-Math.toDegrees(angle), 0d, h1 / 2d, 0d, new Point3D(dir.getX(), -dir.getY(), dir.getZ())));

    return c;
}
```

Как результат:

[image: Cylinder 2 point javaFx]:

теперь ближе к конкретным вопросам:

Так сложилось что легче для понимания процедуры вращения объекта это последовательное  вращение по 3 координатам (и применяется такой подход часто) Но если разобраться то вполне естественный ход поворачивать объект всего один раз на один конкретный угол.И если быть совсем точным поворачивают систему координат дабы на одной плоскости оказались точки начала и конца дуги поворота.
Возможна также работа с [матрицей поворота](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) и как пример работы с ней данный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145414/rotate-a-3d-object-on-3-axis-in-javafx-properly).Да конечно такой подход быстрее чем работа с последовательным поворотом по трем осям но хочу заметить что сам автор ответа(он же к слову и разработчик [библиотеки](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz) -  FXyz) по моим наблюдениям конкретно матричной реализацией не
пользуется (наблюдение рамках открытого кода на GitHub).

Comment: И это решение пока что лучшее из представленных!

Comment: Если не появится ответа ещё более блестящего в течение ближайших 12 часов, премия достанется именно Вам, Peter Slusar!

Comment: @DimXenon сарказм?)Но по существу если есть под вопросы постараюсь ответить.Сам рыскал по сети довольно долго слишком мало информации о построение 3D объектов силами JavaFx.Если быть точнее то очень мало готовых библиотек в большинстве своем приходиться работать очень базовыми методами а не оперировать чем то высокоуровневым :/

Comment: Нет. Я серьёзно. Мне очень понравился Ваш ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Обнаружил, что в случае, когда у соединяемых точек совпадают координаты по оси X и Z, при построении цилиндра из А в В связь строится нормально, а из В в А - цилиндр оказывается повёрнутым в сторону противоположную точке В. (Выглядит так: "В-А-", где В и А - точки, а "-" - цилиндры их "соединяющие".) Как можно обработать эту ситуацию?

Comment: Ситуацию можно контролировать тут new Translate(B.getX(), B.getY() - h1 / 2d, B.getZ() (заменяя точку начала построения) или на этапе работы с осью...Чуть позже проработаю и дополню

Comment: Ок. Добавление множителя "-1" в выражение для Y по условию равенства координат по X и по Z решает проблему. Возможно ли лучше?